# Filtering Excel Data by Row and Copying a Specific Column

Tags: excel, filter, vba

I've been having a bit of trouble with my Excel code. What I want to do is to search the rows by text criteria, filter/sort those rows with the specific criteria by column, and be able to copy and hold all of the values in the clipboard for an automation software to take over from that point.

So far, I have been able to sort the rows by the specified criteria (text string), but I cannot seem to figure out the code to copy only the column range (to the end of the row). I can copy the rows, but I'm not sure what the code is to copy an individual column (in this case these are all web addresses, and the column to be copied would be C). I am using Excel 2010.

```
Sub USPS_Select2()

Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim copyFrom As Range
Dim lRow As Long 
Dim strSearch As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim cl As Object
Dim strMatch As String
Dim filterRange As Range
Dim copyRange As Range
Dim lastRow As Long


Set wb1 = Application.Workbooks.Open("\\S51\CompanyFolder\Employee Folders\Jason\TrackingDeliveryStatus.xls")
Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("TrackingDeliveryStatusResults")

strSearch = "usps.com"


With ws1


    .AutoFilterMode = False


    lRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With .Range("C2:C" & lRow)
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & strSearch & "*"
        Set copyFrom = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
    End With


    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With


Set wb2 = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\CompanyFolder\Desktop\Excel_Test.xls")
Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1")

With ws2
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("A1"), _
                      LookAt:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False).Row

    Else
        lRow = 1
    End If

    copyFrom.Copy .Rows(lRow)
End With




'wb2.Save
'wb2.close
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already working *only* with column C in this statement:

```
With .Range("C2:C" & lRow)
```

You can just eliminate the `EntireRow` property from this statement

```
Set copyFrom = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
```

And it will set the range to visible cells in column C *only*, like this:

```
Set copyFrom = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

### EDIT (to address issue in comment)

The line:

```
copyFrom.Copy .Rows(lRow)
```

Is going to paste the data into *every column* of that row. So make the line this to copy only into Column A.

```
copyFrom.Copy .Cells(lRow,1)
```

Comment: Thanks @Scott, that worked, but now it's copying to every single column down to IV! D: It looks horrendous. 
I only need column C to be copied to Column A either in the same workbook on Sheet2, or to the new Excel_Test workbook, which I am trying to figure out the code for. Either one is fine.

Comment: see my edited answer. technically it's a separate question, but it was simple enough to fix here. please mark as answered (see you say it worked).

Comment: Thanks so much! I will remember these small details for future macros and study on the references further. This just saved me a ton of time with daily operations for URL searching. It's always those small things that get me when I'm coding :(